# Vuex: How to store the result of a getter in the state?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am having a problem in my Vuex.Store:

I would like to get an object (getter.getRecipe) using two state entries as search criteria (state.array & state.selected) with a getter. Then I would like to store that result in my state (state.recipe) in order to be able to update it within components (i.e., changing one key of the recipe object based on client action). 
However, I have no idea how I can store the result of getters in my state ("this.getters.getRecipe" is not working...). 
Very helpful for hints. Thanks a lot.

```
//store.js (vuex store)

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
state: {
   array: [recipe1, recipe2],
   selected: 0,
   recipe: this.getters.getRecipe()
 },
getters: {
   getRecipe: (state) => {
    return state.array[state.selected]
   }
 }
})
```

Comment: You don't that's counter-intuitive. Your state is your state, and your getters are getters.

Comment: instead, you should use your `getters` like getters, and GET data from your state

Comment: getters are cached just like computed properties. So you do not need an extra state property. You can just use the getter `getRecipe`

Comment: @Derek thx for your quick response. The point is, I need a result (which is the manipulation of the current state) and then somehow save that result in the state. How could I do that?

Comment: You cannot because that's not how vuex (and by proxy, the flux pattern) works. It violates one way data flow.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna thx for your quick reply. It is no problem to retrieve the result in a component using the getter, but then I am not able to update the result. I cannot update a getter....

Comment: You can update a getter, you just need to pass it an argument and make it return a function

Comment: whenever the properties the getter is dependent on changes the getter automatically gets updated. So in your case either `state.array` or `state.selected` change will cause the getter to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, you should use [Method style getters with arguments](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#method-style-access):

> You can also pass arguments to getters by returning a function. This is particularly useful when you want to query an array in the store:

A basic example:

```
getters: {
  // ...
  getTodoById: (state) => (id) => {
    return state.todos.find(todo => todo.id === id)
  }
}
```

Then, to use the example:

```
store.getters.getTodoById(2) // -> { id: 2, text: '...', done: false }
```

or, from inside a component:

```
this.$store.getters.getTodoById(2) // -> { id: 2, text: '...', done: false }
```

This way you ensure your state remains a pure data structure that follows the one way data flow set forth by the flux pattern.

Comment: Thx a lot Derek. You helped me making clear that my approach goes against some principles. From here own, I can go on, as my example is of course more complicated. Might post a more specific question again after having proceeded. My key probelm is not getting data, but computing data initially based on customer selection in one component (state.selected) and then giving the customer trough interaction a another component the chance to manipulate that data again (and stored in the store of course. THX MAN!